# SQL: Perform join on multiple tables on Google BigQuery

Tags: join, query, google-bigquery, data

Please, I am running a professional course in data analytics. Right now, I am on my Capstone project. But I am having challenge combining tables in BigQuery using SQL. The data is about bicycle trips on a daily basis from Jan to December- a period of 12 months. The tables are arranged in months with close to 1,000, 000 rows each. What SQL query should I use? I need advice, pls for it has exceeded the capacity of spreadsheet. I have tried using FULL OUTER JOIN with the structure as shown below. But it’s not giving me the expected outcome. I tried using INNER JOIN but it returns “data not available “ as resppnse. Again, what should I do?

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset.table1 AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN dataset.table2 AS t2
ON t1.ride-_id = t2.ride_id
AND T1.ride_length = t2.ride_length
AND t1.day_of_week= t2.day_of_week
```

The list goes on and on

Comment: Show the Create table and add data and wanted result. make  a full [mre]